# Connect stack on server: Vue js frontend + php api + postgres db

Tags: php, postgresql, docker, vue.js, nginx

I'm struggling with setting up/deploying my production environment on a server. My frontend image is built with *Dockerfile.static*

```
FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
LABEL maintainer="xxx"
COPY app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./conf.d/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My nginx config file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.xxx.org;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_pass http://backend:9000/;
    }
}
```

The fontend service is setup via this snippet from my compose file

```
frontend:
    image: gitlab-registry.cern.ch/xxx/xxx/static:latest
    ports:
        - 80:80
    networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
```

The static files are served when I enter the domain in my browser. But I can't get my backend connection going. Only getting 404s.

Here's my the Dockerfile for my php API:

```
FROM bitnami/php-fpm:latest
LABEL maintainer="xxx"
COPY . /var/www/html
WORKDIR /var/www/html/public
```

And the complete compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    backend:
        image: gitlab-registry.cern.ch/xxx/xxx:latest
        expose:
            - 9000
        networks:
            - backend

    frontend:
        image: gitlab-registry.cern.ch/xxx/xxx/static:latest
        ports:
            - 80:80
        networks:
            - frontend
            - backend


    mtg-db:
        container_name: mtg-db
        image: postgres:latest
        env_file:
            - database/database.env
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
             - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            - backend

 volumes:
     db_data:
         driver: local
         driver_opts:
             o: bind
             type: none
             device: home/mtg_web_data/

networks:
    frontend:
    backend:
```

In my backend container, I have an index.php file that needs to be served. In my dev environment I just used the php development server and the content of this file looks like this:

```
<?php


require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../src/api.php";

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

$url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

if (!isset($url["query"])) {
    $url["query"] = NULL;
}

$API = new Api($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"], $url["path"], $url["query"]);
$API->processRequest();

?>
```

The Api class contains all the endpoints and eventually handles all the queries and fetches the data from the DB.

Question 1) What's the correct URL to fetch from in my frontend container? From my understanding, the containers are connected via the docker network *backend*. So I tried *http://backend:9000/* + uri_path ...

Question 2) How do I set up the backend container? Because it feels like I am missing something. The index.php file needs to be served... do I need another nginx container for this and integrate my php API into that container?

Question 3) Is my nginx config correct or am I missing something there too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be useful for people who are not that experienced with deployment to see a basic example of how to do this. So, I wanna provide such an example and what my next steps would be if I were to improve my solution. Feedback is welcome!

### Frontend container

- serves the statics, which you get by building your vue js project
- Dockerfile.static is used for building the container

> ```
> FROM nginx:1.17-alpine
> LABEL maintainer="xxx"
> # copy statics into default html folder of container
> COPY app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
> # use specific config file for nginx 
> COPY nginx_static.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
> CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
> ```

config file for nginx server is taken from [vue js doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx) ... I just needed to add the proxy passes for the URL requests which are performed by my frontend in order to fetch data from the DB

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.xxx.org;
    location / {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location /sets {
      proxy_pass http://backend:9000;
    }
    location /cards {
      proxy_pass http://backend:9000;
    }
    location /types {
      proxy_pass http://backend:9000;
    }
    location /supertypes {
      proxy_pass http://backend:9000;
    }
    location /uploads {
      proxy_pass http://backend:9000;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

- *http://backend:9000* comes from the fact that I'm defining a container network in which my three containers communicate with each other called *backend* and the host port 9000 is connected to the port 9000 of the backend container (see docker-compose)
- having all these proxy passes for my frontend requests, the actual request url addresses that are made in my code reduce to "/" (in dev mode I would use something like http://localhost:8000/)
- as a next step I would add SSL configuration to the config ([as described here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html))

### Backend/API

This Dockerfile is used for building the backend container

```
FROM php:7.4-cli
LABEL maintainer="xxx"
RUN apt-get update
# install pgsql libary which is required in my case
RUN apt-get install -y libpq-dev \
  && docker-php-ext-configure pgsql -with-pgsql=/usr/local/pgsql \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql
COPY . /var/www/MTGWeb
WORKDIR /var/www/MTGWeb/public
# start php development server which listens to port 9000
CMD ["php", "-S", "0.0.0.0:9000"]
```

- using the development server is surely not optimal, but for a small scale project like mine it seemed like the easiest solution (as a next step this should be replaced with another nginx webserver)

### DB

I'm using a standard postgres image to build the DB container. In order to set up the DB connection between backend and DB container you have to use the name of the DB service as a host name (in my case *mtg-db* as you can see in the docker-compose file)

### Deployment

I'm using a gitlab-ci to build my frontend and backend image. My private ssh key is added as an environment variable in my repo in order to allow automated access to the server. After pushing something in my master branch the images are built, pulled on the server and then everything is set up again

```
stages:
    - build-statics
    - build-images
    - deploy_staging

build-statics:
    image: node:latest
    stage: build-statics
    script:
        - cd app
        - npm ci
        - npm run build
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - app/dist
    only:
        - master

backend-image:
    stage: build-images
    tags:
        - docker-image-build
    script:
        - ""
    dependencies: []
    variables:
        TO: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile
    only:
        - master

static-image:
    stage: build-images
    tags:
        - docker-image-build
    script:
        - ""
    dependencies:
        - build-statics
    variables:
        TO: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/static:latest
        DOCKER_FILE: Dockerfile.static
    only:
        - master

before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get -y install git
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get install openssh-client )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

deploy_staging:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    stage: deploy_staging
    script:
        - ssh root@xxx.net "cd .. && cd var/www/mtg-web/ && docker pull gitlab-registry.cern.ch/xxx && docker pull gitlab-registry.cern.ch/xxx/static && docker-compose up -d"
    only:
        - master
```

Containers are set up with this compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    backend:
        image: gitlab-registry.cern.ch/xxx:latest
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        volumes:
            - /home/backend_logs:/var/www/MTGWeb/logs
        networks:
            - backend

    frontend:
        image: gitlab-registry.cern.ch/xxx/static:latest
        ports:
            - 80:80
        networks:
            - backend


    mtg-db:
        container_name: mtg-db
        image: postgres:latest
        env_file:
            - database/database.env
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        volumes:
            - /home/mtg_web_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        networks:
            - backend

volumes:
    db_data:
    backend_logs:

networks:
    backend:
```

And here you go! A full workiong example of how to set up a 3 container stack on your server using a js frontend framework like vue js, a php based API and a postgres DB.